# Transforming Spark SQL AST with extraOptimizations

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I'm wanting to take a SQL string as a user input, then transform it before execution. In particular, I want to modify the top-level projection (select clause), injecting additional columns to be retrieved by the query.

I was hoping to achieve this by hooking into Catalyst using `sparkSession.experimental.extraOptimizations`. I know that what I'm attempting isn't strictly speaking an optimisation (the transformation changes the semantics of the SQL statement), but the API still seems suitable. However, my transformation seems to be ignored by the query executor.

Here is a minimal example to illustrate the issue I'm having. First define a row case class:

```
case class TestRow(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)
```

Then define an optimisation rule which simply discards any projection:

```
object RemoveProjectOptimisationRule extends Rule[LogicalPlan] {
    def apply(plan: LogicalPlan): LogicalPlan = plan transformDown {
        case x: Project => x.child
    }
}
```

Now create a dataset, register the optimisation, and run a SQL query:

```
// Create a dataset and register table.
val dataset = List(TestRow(1, 2, 3)).toDS()
val tableName: String = "testtable"
dataset.createOrReplaceTempView(tableName)

// Register "optimisation".
sparkSession.experimental.extraOptimizations =  
    Seq(RemoveProjectOptimisationRule)

// Run query.
val projected = sqlContext.sql("SELECT a FROM " + tableName + " WHERE a = 1")

// Print query result and the queryExecution object.
println("Query result:")
projected.collect.foreach(println)
println(projected.queryExecution)
```

Here is the output:

```
Query result: 
[1]

== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project ['a]
+- 'Filter ('a = 1)
   +- 'UnresolvedRelation `testtable`

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
a: int
Project [a#3]
+- Filter (a#3 = 1)
   +- SubqueryAlias testtable
      +- LocalRelation [a#3, b#4, c#5]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (a#3 = 1)
+- LocalRelation [a#3, b#4, c#5]

== Physical Plan ==
*Filter (a#3 = 1)
+- LocalTableScan [a#3, b#4, c#5]
```

We see that the result is identical to that of the original SQL statement, without the transformation applied. Yet, when printing the logical and physical plans, the projection has indeed been removed. I've also confirmed (through debug log output) that the transformation is indeed being invoked.

Any suggestions as to what's going on here? Maybe the optimiser simply ignores "optimisations" that change semantics?

If using the optimisations isn't the way to go, can anybody suggest an alternative? All I really want to do is parse the input SQL statement, transform it, and pass the transformed AST to Spark for execution. But as far as I can see, the APIs for doing this are private to the Spark `sql` package. It may be possible to use reflection, but I'd like to avoid that.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you guessed, this is failing to work because we make assumptions that the optimizer will not change the results of the query.

Specifically, we cache the schema that comes out of the analyzer (and assume the optimizer does not change it).  When translating rows to the external format, we use this schema and thus are truncating the columns in the result.  If you did more than truncate (i.e. changed datatypes) this might even crash.

As you can see in [this notebook](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1023043053387187/3743056197112949/2840265927289860/latest.html), it is in fact producing the result you would expect under the covers. We are planning to open up more hooks at some point in the near future that would let you modify the plan at other phases of query execution. See [SPARK-18127](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18127) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this Michael. I've instead gone for the more direct approach of obtaining the AST through package-private methods - I'll outline this in a separate answer.

Comment: @MichaelPedersen Can you please elaborate on what you did to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Michael Armbrust's answer confirmed that this kind of transformation shouldn't be done via optimisations.

I've instead used internal APIs in Spark to achieve the transformation I wanted for now. It requires methods that are package-private in Spark. So we can access them without reflection by putting the relevant logic in the appropriate package. In outline:

```
// Must be in the spark.sql package.
package org.apache.spark.sql

object SQLTransformer {
    def apply(sparkSession: SparkSession, ...) = {

        // Get the AST.
        val ast = sparkSession.sessionState.sqlParser.parsePlan(sql)

        // Transform the AST.
        val transformedAST = ast match {
            case node: Project => // Modify any top-level projection 
            ...
        }

        // Create a dataset directly from the AST.
        Dataset.ofRows(sparkSession, transformedAST)
    }
}
```

Note that this of course may break with future versions of Spark.

Comment: It will be wonderful if you give more details on the implementation. Some end-to-end hello world example it's OK.